# Can a mote of dust create a rainbow/prism like effect if floating inside the light of a sunbeam and seen from the right angle and/or device?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, refraction, nature

The device could be a telescope, microscope, camera, or anything that zooms in with great clarity. I'm pretty sure that lots of dust together in one place in a sunbeam can have this effect (please correct me if I'm wrong) but can a single mote produce it? Also, what causes this effect and what circumstances must be present for it to happen? I would be happy to know any and all details about this phenomenon that anyone can offer. Thank you!

Comment: A single small body produces a diffraction pattern similar to an Airy disk. There are certainly color fringes when the diffracted light has a white spectrum.  Is that particularly colorful, like a prism? No, I wouldn't say so, but that's my personal opinion. I have seen these in microscopes at high magnification, but I can't say for certain whether the pattern is caused by the microscope's optics or the dust particles themselves. The conventional wisdom seems to be that we are seeing mostly the diffraction pattern of the microscope's lenses. I pass that to someone from the optics department.

Comment: Amongst many other possible things (because it is quite strongly dependent upon the size of the dust particle), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering can happen, and so yes, it could work. But if the dust is too big or small it will not. And with only one dust particle it will be really difficult to see anything, especially those angles close to the initial supremely bright beam.

Comment: Is that what these are? https://westernhillsheating.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/dust-particles-in-a-sunbeam-min.jpg https://live.staticflickr.com/5695/23045285830_09cc6956cc_b.jpg